# Using Euler's formula

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

I have a question related to Euler's formula and whilst I understand the formula I'm  not really sure about the question:
Let $V_{k}$ be the number of vertices of P from which exactly k edges emanate, and $F_{k}$ be
the number of faces of P with exactly k edges. Explain why we have the equalities:
$3V_{3} + 4V_{4} + 5V_{5} + · · · = 2E = 3F_{3} + 4F_{4} + 5F_{5} + · · ·$

Can anyone explain this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

All three of the allegedly equal quantities count each edge twice.  That's obvious for the middle item, $2E$.  For the left, count the "ends" of edges, where I mean that each edge has two ends, located at the two vertices that it joins.  There are $V_k$ vertices each serving as an end for $k$ edges, so they contribute $kV_k$ ends altogether.  To get the total count of ends-of-edges, we have to add the contributions for all possible $k$, and so we get the LHS of your equation.  For the RHS, count the "sides" of edges, where I mean that each edge has two sides, namely the two faces that it borders.  Each face with $k$ sides contributes $k$ sides-of-edges, so all faces with $k$ sides contribute $kF_k$ sides-of-edges, and all faces together contribute the sum over all $k$, namely the RHS of your equation.

Comment: Note that your equation doesn't depend on Euler's formula.  It is, however, often used together with Euler's formula to get additional information.